# Read table from PDF using pdftools

Tags: r, regex, text-extraction

I'm trying to extract tabular data from a character vector produced by `pdftools` package. The output (when trimmed) looks like this:

```
pdftext <- c("   Clostridium perfringens     no./100ml         0        0          0        0      1409       0          0\n     Colony count 22°C           cfu/ml          -        0      15.673 >300.000       52       0          0\n     Colony count 37°C           cfu/ml          -        0       3.942      41        52       0          0")
lines <- strsplit(pdftext,"\n")
lines
[[1]]
[1] "   Clostridium perfringens     no./100ml         0        0          0        0      1409       0          0"
[2] "     Colony count 22°C           cfu/ml          -        0      15.673 >300.000       52       0          0"
[3] "     Colony count 37°C           cfu/ml          -        0       3.942      41        52       0          0"
```

I've been splitting and joining these into a character matrix using:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(lines, function(x) {strsplit(x," [ ]+")})[[1]])
```

This fails because there is only one space between the column containing `15.673 >300.000`.

There might be more than one question here:

1. how do I pass a character vector to read.fwf?
2. can you suggest a better regular expression which splits `15.673 >300.000` but not `Colony count 22°C`?
3. is there simpler way to split apart this table? My code all looks a bit clumsy.

Thank you.

Comment: not perfect but `read.table(text = pdftext, row.names = NULL)` is close

Comment: or `read.csv(text = gsub(' {2,}|(?=>)', ',', trimws(pdftext), perl = TRUE), row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: @rawr `read.table` (and `read.fwf`) give this error "'file' must be a character string or connection". I should have elaborated in question 1. Your `read.csv` code looks better except the first line is becoming the column headings

Comment: @rawr I found your regular expression useful. I learned some more PCRE compatible syntax and used a negative lookbehind which worked `(?<![A-z0-9\\.&\\-()]) {1,}| {1,}(?=[>])`. That's a lot more regexp than I've done before. Your suggestion nudged me to learn it. Thanks.

Comment: you can add this as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted 3 questions. This is an answer to the RegExp question (2).

@rawr helped with a better PCRE expression but as I worked through the 500 reports I found more problems. I couldn't find a rule which could cope with all variations, so better RegExp wouldn't have solved the problem. Column boundaries also varied so fixed width wouldn't have solved the problem unless I detected columns for each page.

I solved the problem by parsing the output twice. On the first pass I split by `{2,}` (ie >=2 spaces) and took the first 2 columns of text. On the second pass I split by `{1,}` (ie >=1 space) and took the last 7 columns of numbers. Both passes were coerced to data frames of character vectors and then `cbind` combined them.